# ReactJS: Render an object with keys with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to reactjs/es6 and I'm trying to render an object that looks like this in `console.log()`:

```
Object
0: {_id: "5ceea2eb0023ee3bcc730cc7", createdAt: "2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z", modifiedA: "2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z", sku: "SUP", name: "Superior", …}
1: {_id: "5ceebf7ea686a03bccfa67bf", createdAt: "2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z", modifiedA: "2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z", sku: "ULT", name: "Ultimate", …}
2: {_id: "5ceec48fa686a03bccfa67c4", createdAt: "2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z", modifiedA: "2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z", sku: "PRO", name: "Professional", …}
```

I have tried to do this with `map()` as well as with other methods but I am unable to get it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
return(
         Object.keys(prods).map((key, i) => (prods[key].map((product, ind) =>
              <div key={ind}>
               <h3>{product.name}</h3>
             </div>
            )
        ))
    )
```

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to access that data, that way I can render it into a div or something.

#### EDIT:

This is how I made it work and modified into after I was put in the right direction. Thank you everyone!

```
let prodlist = Object.values(prods).map((product, ind) => (
  <Container>
    <h3>{product.name}</h3>
  </Container>
 ));
    
return(    
   {prodlist}
)
```

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean with `map` ? it is map function in `Array` object ?

Comment: Where is the object coming from?

Comment: @yovie it is an object, either map or any way that I can access that data so that I can render it.

Comment: It matters where the object is coming from. Documentation on the respective source will show you how best to iterate records in the results, whether that's mongodb, or some other database.

Comment: Use `Object.values` instead of keys

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it is from MongoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update your components `render()` logic to use `Object.values()`, to extract the values of the input `prods` object. You'd then `map()` each array item to a JSX template like this:

```
return <React.Fragment> 
{ 
    Object.values(prods).map((product) => (<div key={product._id}>
        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
    </div>))
}
</React.Fragment>
```

An extra note relating to the `key` prop - it's best to supply a `key` values that identifies the `item` in the list being rendered (rather than the current index of the `item` in the list). Assuming that the `_id` field of each item in `prods` is unique, that data would be better suited for the `key` prop than `ind`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for that - very good point. Just updated to use the `product._id` for the key. My understanding is that the `<>` syntax for Fragments is limited to the latest version(s) of react?

Comment: That is correct, which is why I added the stipulation regarding support.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Fragments at all here.

Comment: A fragment is an array equivalent in JSX, you're not required to use JSX.

Comment: I am not using Fragmens at all. But I used this answer to get what I wanted to do. Thank you so much !! @DacreDenny

Comment: @EmileBergeron this assumes one of the recent (can't remember which) releases of react 16  right?

Comment: @DacreDenny it assumes 16.2.0 and up, but saying it's a recent release in the JS world is blasphemy :P It's almost two years old!

Comment: Oh, even 16 as 16.2.0 is when they introduced shorthand fragments.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings

Comment: @EmileBergeron very true - I'm out of date already! Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @EmileBergeron it appears you were correct, my apologies. I guess the linting tools for my last project were out of date, because they generated errors whenever I tried to omit the fragment syntax when rendering multiple components.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't need to use `map` to `prods[key]` because it isn't array

```
return(
         Object.keys(prods).map((key, i) => (
              <div key={prods[key]._id}>
               <h3>{prods[key].name}</h3>
             </div>
        ))
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing you need to do is map the `object array`, then read the keys and values inside that object.

This is the way to get keys and values in object array.

```
   render() {
        const obj = [{_id: "5ceea2eb0023ee3bcc730cc7", createdAt: "2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z", modifiedA: "2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z", sku: "SUP", name: "Superior"},
          {_id: "5ceebf7ea686a03bccfa67bf", createdAt: "2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z", modifiedA: "2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z", sku: "ULT", name: "Ultimate"},
          {_id: "5ceec48fa686a03bccfa67c4", createdAt: "2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z", modifiedA: "2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z", sku: "PRO", name: "Professional"}
        ]

        return(
          <>
            {obj.map((item, i) => (
              Object.keys(item).map(key=>{
                return <div>
                  <h3>key: {key}, value: {item[key]}</h3>
                </div>
              })             
            ))}
          </>
        )
      }
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it prints `key: _id, value: 5ceea2eb0023ee3bcc730cc7
key: createdAt, value: 2015-01-25T05:00:00.000Z
key: modifiedA, value: 2019-05-28T04:00:00.000Z`. I tried that